# Handle Onclick event with a view visibility gone/visible

Tags: android, view, visibility

I explain my problem.

I have a view in which there is two button and two editText.
If I touch the button1, I want to display the edidText1. 
If I touch the button2, I want to display the edidText2.

In my layout, edidText1 has the visibility visible, edidText2 has the visibility gone.

**My_Layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_comments1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/form_comments"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_comments2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_comments1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="top" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_comments2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="top" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my onCreate function

```
final EditText etComments1 = (EditText) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_comments);
etComments1.setText(comment1);
etComments1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "TODO_1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

final EditText etComments2 = (EditText) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_mes_corr);
etComments2.setText(comment2);
etComments2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "TODO_2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});


final Button btnComments1 = (Button) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_comments1);
final Button btnComments2 = (Button) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_comments2);

btnComments2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        etComments1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        etComments2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});

btnComments1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        etComments1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        etComments2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

When first click on my etComments1, the TODO_1 is call.
After I click on my btnComments2 to display etComments2, and when I click on it, the TODO_2 is not called.
After I click on my btnComments1 to display etComments1, and when I click on it, the TODO_1 is not called.

So I was thinking that can come the the view.Gone. So I implemented also thi event in the onClick on the button, but the problem is still the same.

Someone can help me?

Comment: How do you know it isn't called? It is only a comment so there's no code to run there. What exactly are you expecting to happen and why do you want to click on an `EditText` view?

Comment: I didn't put the exact code that should be call in the function.

Comment: try adding `android:clickable="true"` to your `EditText`s. You may also need `android:editable="false" `

Comment: I tried with `android:clickable="true" ` but that change anything. adding `android:editable="false"`, it still not that but it is a little better, to have the onclick called, I need to click twice.

Comment: It's been awhile so not positive but you might try `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` also. Can you explain a little of what you want to happen? There might be a better way

Comment: When I click on the edittext, I want to show a dialog in order to ask to the user if I want to modify the text. I can also show a dialog in order to say to the user that he can't modify the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding `android:focusable="false"` and `android:clickable="true"`, I believe the problem is that the `EditText` is gaining focus on the first click then the second click will call the listener.

Try adding

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to your `EditText`s and that should allow  a single tap to call the listener.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

The problem is in the layout file and somewhat in the code. You have used visibility:gone for edittext2 and if you read the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility) then you will understand that "gone" means "Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added."

So you shouldn't use "gone" attribute if you want to keep the view. Also why have you declared your variables final? It's not necessary. I hope it helps  :)

layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_comments1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:gravity="top" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_comments2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="top" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_comments1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="button 2"
        android:id="@+id/btn_comments2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by sonnet on 2/17/15.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button1;
Button button2;

EditText editText1;
EditText editText2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_comments1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_comments2);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_comments1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_comments2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editText2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            int height = 0;
            int width = 0;

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            editText2.setLayoutParams(params);

            height = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            editText1.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            editText2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            int height = 0;
            int width = 0;

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            editText1.setLayoutParams(params);

            height = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            editText2.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
    });


    editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "edittext1 is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    editText2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "edittext2 is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers on SO are rarely desireable. Please consider adding an explanation as to what you've changed and why it should work for the OP

Comment: when I set the `view.INVISIBLE`, my activity is not display like I need. I need it completely hidden. I really need one or the other in the same place depending on switch one the user want. And in your answer, that not explain my how to set the onClickListen on the EditText. Also I use the final in order to not declare as a class variable because this layout is use in a listview so it is set several time.